# how to save image from Byte Array in Asp Web Api 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, http-post, httpclient, image-uploading

I want to do pass Image object by `BsonMediaTypeFormatter` to web api to save image on server and image url in database.

I have done following code but not work well. break in `Bitmap btmap = new Bitmap(ms);`

Upload object:

```
public class UploadCategoryDTO
{

    public string CategoryTitle { get; set; }

    public byte[] Picture { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

and Post Action:

```
 [ResponseType(typeof(UploadCategoryDTO))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostCategoryModel(UploadCategoryDTO categoryUploadModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        CategoryModel categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
        categoryModel.CategoryTitle = categoryUploadModel.CategoryTitle;
        categoryModel.Date = categoryUploadModel.Date;
        var folderName = "Picture";
        string filename = folderName + "/" + categoryUploadModel.CategoryTitle + ".png";
        var PATH = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/" + filename);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(categoryUploadModel.Picture))
        {
            Bitmap btmap = new Bitmap(ms);
            btmap.Save(PATH, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        }
        string baseuri = "http://localhost:13566/";

        categoryModel.PictureUri = baseuri + filename;
        db.CategoryModels.Add(categoryModel);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = categoryModel.ID }, categoryModel);
    }
```